# ReactJS: backend.js:6 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I have a datepicker that is conditionally rendered based on what type of change a user wants to make, being “future” or “permanent”:

The first time the datepicker is rendered I see this warning:

backend.js:6 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. 
 in Anonymous (created by DatePicker)

```
I’m not sure why this is happening but I tried to change the logic to the following but that has not worked either:
```

```
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(props.input.value);
        const ref = React.createRef();
        const onChange = useCallback(date => setStartDate(date), []);
        return (
            <DatePicker
                selected={startDate}
                onChange={() => onChange}
```

and this is my Datepicker:

```
const ButtonImage = ({onClick}) => (
    <div onClick={onClick} className="button-container">
        <img src="https://mcontent/static_assets/Media/icon-calendar.svg" />
    </div>
);
ButtonImage.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func
};
const CustomInput = React.forwardRef((props, refs) => {
    const inputProps = props.inputProps;
    inputProps.input.onChange(props.value);
    return (
        <div className="input-button">
            <FormattedTextInput
                {...inputProps}
                ref={refs}
                onFocus={props.onFocus}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                helpText={<span aria-hidden="true">YYYY-MM-DD | HH:MM</span>}
            />
        </div>
    );
});
CustomInput.propTypes = {
    inputProps: PropTypes.object,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string
};
const DateTimePicker = props => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
    const ref = React.createRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.input.value === '') {
            setStartDate(null);
        }
    }, [props.input.value]);
    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
            minDate={moment()}
            customInput={<CustomInput inputProps={props} ref={ref} />}
            showTimeSelect
            disabledKeyboardNavigation
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={15}
            timeCaption="time"
            dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
        />
    );
};
DateTimePicker.propTypes = {
    input: PropTypes.object
};
```

This is how I call the datepicker:

```
    {this.props.searchPageFormData && this.props.searchPageFormData.type === 'F' && (
                                <FormSection className="page-subheader" label="Date">
                                    <FormGroup>
                                        <Field
                                            className="input"
                                            component={DateTimePicker}
                                            label="Future Date"
                                            name="futureDate"
                                            validate={[required, validDateTimeFormat]}
                                            formatting="9999-99-99 99:99"
                                        />
                                    </FormGroup>
                                </FormSection>
                            )}
```

Comment: The problem is probably `inputProps.input.onChange(props.value)` if calling it will cause `CustomInput` to be re-rendered, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: I changed it to this:
 const onChange= useCallback(props => inputProps.input.onChange(props.value), []);
    return (
        <div className="input-button">
            <FormattedTextInput
                {...inputProps}
                ref={refs}
                onFocus={props.onFocus}
                onChange={onChange}
                helpText={<span aria-hidden="true">YYYY-MM-DD | HH:MM</span>}
            />
        </div>

Comment: but I still get the warning

Comment: My point is that if calling `inputProps.input.onChange` changes any of `CustomInput`'s properties, you'll have an infinite loop. Is not just the `inputProps.input.onChange` function that has to be constant, is all of this component's properties. Also, is not clear why you're calling this function on each render.